# Выбор изображения из галереи MVVMCross

Tags: android, c#

В axml описана кнопка, по клику на кнопку, нужно открыть галерею и передать в ViewModel путь к выбранному изображению.
Реализация в рамках MVVMCross, нужен именно путь, так как он будет сохранятся в бд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь необходимо создать обьект, после взаимодействия с которым будет вызван метод CreateImageIntent();

```
private void CreateImageIntent()
    {
        var imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent , "Select photo") , 0);
    }
```

После выбора изображения и закрытия Активити галереи будет вызван метод

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode , Android.App.Result resultCode , Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode , resultCode , data);
        if (resultCode == Android.App.Result.Ok)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            imgPath.ImageUrl = uri.Path;
            ImgPathHolder.ImgPathString = GetRealPathFromURI(uri);

        }
    }
```

А метод GetRealPathFromURI(); - вернет нам путь, который можно забиндить к ImageView

```
private string GetRealPathFromURI(Android.Net.Uri contentURI)
    {
        ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(contentURI , null , null , null , null);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        string path = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.Data));
        cursor.Close();

        return path;
    }
```